# Save data in a plist and accessing this data

Tags: database, save, plist

I would know if it's possible to save data in a plist document and how accessing to it through the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plist is nothing more than an xml document.  It would be useful to know what programming language are you wanting to use as well.  Objective-c for the iPhone has support through NSDictionary.  .NET has some interpreters out there as well.

```
NSDictionary *myDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: So I can acces to the file with a NSDictionary! Thanks!! ;)